# Skype is not connecting for some user accounts

Tags: windows-xp, skype

I have a Windows XP system and installed the latest version of Skype 5.8 on this. when I connect this through administrator account on domain then it works fine but when I connect this via another account for domain on this system then it shows "Skype can't connect". IE7 for Windows is working fine.

Note: On another system with both users its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by changing the .xml file.

Comment: What exactly did you do? Can you explain?

Comment: I changed the .xml which having without proxy settings for connection and again I reset the proxy setting and port no.